How can I build two node/next builds with different environment variables from the same code, at the same time?
What I'm trying to do is launch the same app in two different ports, with one variable changed between the two.
I'm currently trying this by creating two different builds pulling the variable from two separate environment. My package.json contains this:
        "build:ui": "env-cmd -f .env.ui next build",
        "build:monitoring": "env-cmd -f .env.monitoring next build",
        "start": "next start --port 50013",
        "start:ui": "env-cmd -f .env.ui next start --port 50013",
        "start:monitoring": "env-cmd -f .env.monitoring next start --port 50014",


I am able to run each build as expected. However, as soon as I reload the build I ran first, it changes and updates to the information from the other build, which was run most latest.
I want to be able to run both builds at the same time without having either update to the each others env variable when the latest one is run.
